# What does deploy:initial do in Capistrano task

Tags: capistrano

I use Capistrano for deploy. My Capistrano tasks are almost quoted from many blogs. I often find following structure.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Say something before Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:hoge', 'deploy:bazz'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  task :hoge do
    on roles(:app) do
      puts "'hello, world'"
    end
  end

  task :bazz do
    on roles(:app) do
      puts "'goodnight, world'"
    end
  end
end
```

What does `before 'deploy:hoge', 'deploy:bazz'` do in `task` statement? It doesn't display any messages. I think `before` statement must be outside of `task` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Capistrano 3.x at least, there is no such thing as a built-in `deploy:initial` task. Declaring a task with that name does not do anything special.

> I think `before` statement must be outside of task statement.

You are exactly right. Any `before` and `after` declarations should be done at the top level and never within a `task` block.

As it stands, the example that you gave does nothing. If you want to run a certain task before deploy begins, you would hook into the `deploy:starting` task, like this:

```
before "deploy:starting", "deploy:hoge"
```

Furthermore, there is nothing special about the `deploy` namespace. I recommend declaring your own custom tasks in a different namespace, to keep them visually separated. Then you can easily distinguish between a built-in Capistrano task and your custom ones.

So I would rewrite the example like this:

```
namespace :myapp do
  task :hoge do
    on roles(:app) do
      puts "'hello, world'"
    end
  end

  task :bazz do
    on roles(:app) do
      puts "'goodnight, world'"
    end
  end
end

# Invoke hoge and bazz before deployment begins
before "deploy:starting", "myapp:hoge"
before "deploy:starting", "myapp:bazz"
```

The full list of built-in Capistrano task that you can use with `before` and `after` can be found here:

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/